# `conda build gcc-5` Fails on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: gcc, conda, conda-build

Using conda, I can not seem to build gcc-5 (or any gcc-X version) recipe on MacOS Mojave:

#### System pre-reqs

- Install Xcode
- Command Line Tools
- Install headers package (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg)
- Run Xcode, to finalize the install.

#### Conda pre-reqs

- Install Conda, conda-build
- Obtain conda-recipes:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:conda/conda-recipes.git
```

#### Do the Sysroot stuff ([as instructed by Anaconda compiler builds](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/compiler-tools.html#macos-sdk))

Which in a nut shell means:

- Download and extract MacOSX10.9 SDK to /opt/MacOSX10.9.sdk
- Build the ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml

```
 macos_min_version:
   - 10.9
 macos_machine:
   - x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
 MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:
   - 10.9
 CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT:            # [osx]
   - /opt/MacOSX10.9.sdk         # [osx]
```

- Instruct conda to use the above config file (~/.condarc):

```
conda_build:
  config_file: ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
```

#### Attempt to build gcc-5:

```sh
cd conda-recipes
conda build gcc-5 -c conda-forge
```

The above build fails. Pointing at atomic headers in Xcode. My assumption, is that Xcode 10.2.x is *too new* to build such an old gcc compiler? I have also tried to build my own conda gcc-9 recipe, but fail with missing images (dylibs not found/loaded). So I guess my real question, is what do folks do to build gcc-X using conda build? I can build GCC 9.2.0 manually on my own. But I wish to know how to properly do it *using* conda build.

**Note to Stackoverflow guys:** I think this question should be asked on SuperUser, but there is no tag 'conda'. Everyone seems to be posting conda questions here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coda-recipes is deprecated, see [README.md](https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/blob/master/README.md), [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) is the replacement.

On conda-forge, check out [clangdev-feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/clangdev-feedstock).

Comment: You can also look into https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/clangdev